# K means clustering on matrices instead of data

Tags: algorithm, matlab, k-means, vlfeat

In matlab, I can cluster the data matrix like

```
[centers, assignments] = vl_kmeans(da, 3);
```

all the data points in matrix "da" will be divided into 3 clusters.

But, instead of data points, I want to cluster the complete matrices. I have hundreds of matrices of 128*19 and I would like to divide these matrices into five groups.

For example

if there are 11 matrices if 128*19,

After Clustering, I should be able to figure out:

```
Cluster 1: 1, 7, 11
Cluster 2: 2,4,6,8,10
Cluster 3: 3,5,9
```

That is center 1 will return the matrices number 1,7,11

How can I achieve this in matlab?
Any help/pointer is highly appreciated.

( These 128*19 matrices contains the SIFT descriptors of images, and based on the the classification of these descriptors I would be classifying images)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert each matrix into a vector of 128*19 length, and concatenate your "matrix vectors" into one huge matrix, which you can cluster as usual.

edit

One important note - **kmeans** is a **clustering** not **classification** algorithm. Kmeans may be used to help classification to reduce the number of descriptors, but not as a classification tool.

edit 2

trivial example:

Having 3 matrices od size 2x2

```
matrix 1: 
[[1, 2], 
 [2, 3]]

matrix 2: 
[[4, 5], 
 [5, 6]]

matrix 3: 
[[7, 7], 
 [8, 9]]
```

You can convert them to one big matrix of size 3x4 ( 3x(2*2) )

```
[ [1,2,2,3],
  [4,5,5,6],
  [7,7,8,9] ]
```

and use your matlab clustering to cluster it. Each row is one of your original matrices, so you get exactly what you need

Comment: Would'nt this clustering will treat every matrix element individually?

Comment: I do not understand your question. If you can cluster data points in the form of matrix, then simply convert the data into this format, as described.

Comment: I know I could not do good job in explaning my question, I have modified the question though...

Comment: I meant your question in the comment. My answer is still valid for the "original question" (with the edit)

Comment: Bundles of thanks, your example made it very clear, I am just starting with matlab so having these small confusions, can you please just verify if the syntax I am using is correct or not to achieve this:
da1 = da1';
da1 = da1(:);
da1 = da1';

da2 = da2';
da2 = da2(:);
da2 = da2';

D = [da1; da2];